# JPA ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException on an Insert sql execution followed by an Update sql execution

Tags: java, kotlin, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring-data-jpa with Kotlin and I faced this error:

```
org.springframework.orm.ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1; statement executed
```

Here is my parent entity (unnecessary parts are omitted):

```
@Entity
class Parent(
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  val id: Long = 0L,

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], orphanRemoval = true)
  val children: MutableList<Child> = mutableListOf()
) {

  fun addChild(child: Child) {
    this.children.add(child)
    child.parent = this
  }
}
```

Here is my child entity (omitted too):

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = [UniqueConstraint(columnNames = ["parent_id"])]
class Child(
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  val id: Long = 0L,
) {

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
  lateinit var parent: Parent
}
```

Transactional code is simple as follows:

```
@Transactional
fun saveChildren() {
  ...
  val parent: Parent = parentRepo.findById(parentId)
  parent.addChild(Child())
  parent.addChild(Child())
  validateSavedChildren()   // select all children data to validate for some business reason
  parentRepo.save(parent)
}
```

I turn on the sql log for debugging and the sqls are like (It assumes the parent's id = 4):

```
insert into
  child
  (... parent_id) 
  values
  (... 4)
enter code here

...

select
  .... parent_id
from Child
where parent_id = 4

...

update Child
set
 parent_id = 4
 ...
where id = 1
```

The query parameters are just correct. As I guess, the error occurred by the last update sql and also know what the error means. I think the data in insert sql is not yet visible when the update sql is executed. Why I'm thinking this way is because I tried to reproduce the error with debug mode with my IDE(IntelliJ) and I executed the codes line by line, and the error is disappeared. Is this common case in JPA??

What I really wonder is the reason why the update sql is executed. It seems useless because the setting data in update sql is just the same as insert sql. After some Internet research, I found out some cases that update happens after insert, but none of them fits my case.

I also tried to change one line of code:

```
parentRepo.saveAndFlush(parent)
```

It made the upate sql disappear and the error is gone forever.
Why does this happen?? What am I missing??

**UPDATE**
Here is the function validateSavedChildren code:

```
fun validateSavedChildren() {
  val parents: List<Parant> parentRepo.findAll()  // it select all parents in DB
  var childrenCount = 0
  parents.forEach { parent -> 
    childrenCount += parent.children.size
  }
  if (childrenCount > CHILDREN_LIMIT) {
    throw ChildrenCountExceededLimitException()
  }
}
```

Following a comment by @XtremeBaumer, It seems like the above function has the key point because the update sql execution is removed by erasing the above function call.

Comment: Can you provide the full code for `saveChildren()` and `validateSavedChildren()`? There might be a reason in there

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I think you have the key point that I'm missing. I updated the question.

Comment: `validateSavedChildren(parent)` is in your code, but the method you posted has no parent parameter? Also `val parents: List<**Parant**>`?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I'm sorry. that parameter, 'parent' is a mistake. I cannot provide the code for my company's security reason so I just tried to write logically same code. the method, 'validateSavedChildren' is to query all the parent entities in DB and iterate it for counting the size of children. That's all.

Comment: Why not query all children and count them? If you have to the route with the parents, I would do it before even calling `saveChildren()` in a different transactional method. That way you can be sure not to interfere. If I am not mistaken, `val parent: Parent = parentRepo.findById(parentId)` does "lock" your parent entity. Then you query that entity again with `parentRepo.findAll()` in the same transaction, causing your exception

Comment: The query in validateSavedChildren is forcing your provider to flush the persistence context, and this picks up the changes made to parent that added two children. This should be expected. What isn't is the second set of update, which seem to be related to the parentRepo.save(parent) call. This save call is unnecessary, and should be a no-op, but apparently is resulting in extra updates to the child entries. Can you show what is actually changed in those statements? It would seem a bug in Spring's save impl or the provider (hibernate?) if nothing has changed.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer parentRepo.findById(parentId) does not lock an entity, and if it did (some custom implementation detail), the locks in the database are reentrant; you should be able to query for the same entity in the same transaction even with a pessimistic read lock. FindAll isn't causing the exception, it'll be the second flush (or commit) of the transaction after the save call. This seems to be executing on a connection that isn't apart of the initial transaction that inserted the children, and the provider thinks the children exist but are blank. This could be a transaction manager issue